# How can I include CSS file in freemarker

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I'm making a website with spring-boot & spring-security which prefers to supply freemarker as view. I don't know **ftl** much, and now I need use adminLTE's CSS and JS files in my **ftl**, but how?

```
<html lang="en">
<#assign basePath=request.contextPath>
<#macro head>
    ...
    <script src="${basePath}WEB-INF/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <link src="${basePath}WEB-INF/AdminLTE/plugins/iCheck/line/line.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="${basePath}WEB-INF/AdminLTE/plugins/iCheck/icheck.js"></script>
    ...
<#macro>
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the path to your file? or you don't know how to call the file in freemarker? You can rename a html file to .ftl and it still works

Comment: Please don't post an image of code; just copy and paste the text itself into your question, select it, and press Ctrl-K. Also, applying the correct tags is quite important in getting the right people seeing this. For instance, I know a lot about JS, HTML, & CSS, but I have no idea what "ftl" or "freemaker" are. I'm guessing you mean "freemarker"... Update as needed.

Comment: omg, it's freemarker .and the question is that i dont know how call my css and js file in freemarker

Comment: and just now , i find that i could call my css file in this way:
<style type="text/css">
<#include "../style/one.css">
</style>

Answer (score 5):

you can include css file by using `<#include >` tag,
place the stylesheet in the directory and use the
`<#include "/{path to style sheet}/Styles.css">`

and make sure your style sheet is inside the styles element:

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
```

Example of this approach is

Test Template

```
<html>
<head>
<#include "css/test.css">
</head>
<body>
.......................
</body>
</html>
```

test.css

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background-color:#C5C5C0;}
*{font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
</style>
```

Comment: the css&js file my ftl need isnot small ,will the include make my ftl too heavy?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare some param in code and use it to fill full path to css

```
// in java
params.put("htmlIncludePath", "classpath:/templates/pdfTemplates/include/");
...
// in ftl
<link href="${htmlIncludePath}manrope.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

physically files should be located in src/main/resources/templates/pdfTemplates/include

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple solution.

I created a dedicated Get method for css-s.

```
@GetMapping(value="/css/{cssFile}") 
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getFile(@PathVariable("cssFile") String cssFile) throws IOException {
    
            InputStream in = getClass()
                    .getResourceAsStream("/css/" + cssFile);
            try {
                return in.readAllBytes();
    
            } catch (Exception e){
                var error = new String("ERROR: css file (/css/" + cssFile + ") not found");
                return error.getBytes();
            }
        }
```

Now I can reference the css file in the usual html way right in .ftlh file. Just need to put my file under resources/css/ directory.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
...
```

Please also note that the suggested method (see other responses) with include statement, will produce a html file with full content of the corresponding css file not a link to css. So if you have heavy css files expect that their content will be literally included into html files received by clients.